# Why control is not going inside the if () , still the condition is satisfied?

Tags: vba, excel

Condition is satisfied but still the control is not going inside the IF().
c has "To be uploaded" & equal the value through I am comparing but control is not going inside. Am I using any wrong syntax , but it's working well for some other files.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at the tooltip, there appears to be at least one space following the text:

> [image]

Hence it will *not* be equal to a string holding the text without a space.

If you want it to catch strings with spaces on the end, I suggest you use `rtrim()` or even `trim()` if you want leading spaces ignored as well.

You could also use `lcase()` to ignore any issues with upper and lower case as well. Putting both those into effect would be something like:

```
If LCase(Trim(c)) = "to be uploaded" Or LCase(Trim(c)) = "to be loaded" Then ...
```

Comment: what will be the format in
Set Foundcell = tmpSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Find(What:="To be Uploaded")
same things are happening here that the control is not finding "To be uploaded" .
can u please help me out in this?

Comment: but there is a row starting with "To be Uploaded" still it was not taking

Answer (score 1):

try

```
IF LCase(Trim(c)) = "to be uploaded" THEN
  ...
END IF
```